# What does M mean in DI Deposit futures contract?

Tags: fixed-income, interest-rates, futures, derivatives, margin

I am trying to understand the forumla for DI1 Brazilian deposit future contract.  I am able to figure out everything except M in the following formula:

Xt=N×M×(Pt−Pt−1Ft)

Lets say if we want to compute daily margin on 200 contracts and trade price is 7.68 and closing market price is 7.89.  Assuming days to day prior to expiration (n) is 14.  On the opening day of the position, would the daily margin in this case be:

(100000/((1+7.86/100)^(14/252)) - 100000/((1+7.89/100)^(14/252)) )   x  200

= 2155.81

I dont get why we need to multiply above number by M?

Any idea?

Comment: If you haven't found it already, then this [document](http://www.bmf.com.br/bmfbovespa/pages/contratos2/pdf/IDfutures.pdf) might be of help (*pp. 3 - 6*).

Comment: Hmm.. so does that mean M is 1 ?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I believe it is a way to convert the daily settlement value ($AD_t$) to Brazilian reals instead of having it in unit price $PU$.